# How to switch between php versions

Tags: php, mamp

MAMP homepage shows the current php version used by the server (5.4.10). In the `conf` folder, there is several other php versions that I need to switch to one of them. How to do that with MAMP? thanx.
[image]

Comment: Those are simply installation folders. Open the configuration file (httpd). In the file you can select the version you wish to use. Hover if I remember correctly it was possible to select the PHP version directly by selecting it in settings in CP and rebooting the server.

Comment: I lready changed the value in httpd file, retsrat the server, after restart the old value is set back and the phpinfo show the old value.

Comment: I found it, Click `MAMP-->Preferences-->PHP tab` and select the version you want to switch to, click OK.